# Does static keyword have any effect on constants?

Tags: php, class, static, constants

```
class A{
  const FOO = 1;
}

class B extends A{

  const FOO = 5;

  function foo(){
    print self::FOO;
    print static::FOO;
  }
}

$b = new B;
$b->foo();
```

It prints 5 in both cases.

So there's no difference in using static vs self on constants?

Comment: I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC`. Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Apparently using `static` as a scope only works in PHP 5.3 and above. Do you have a lower version of PHP? That could be the source of the error.

Comment: I ran it on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/6uCJrbFv), looks like their version is 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) there is a difference.

Consider this code:

```
<?php

class A {
    const FOO = 1;

    function bar() {
        print self::FOO;
        print "\n";
        print static::FOO;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    const FOO = 5;
}

$b = new B;
$b->bar();  // 1 5
```

If you run this code, the output will be:

```
1
5
```

When referencing `self::FOO`, the value of `1` is printed (even though `bar()` was called on class `B`, but when the `static` keyword was used, late static binding took effect and it referenced the `FOO` constant from `B` rather than `A` when using the static keyword.

This is relevant for PHP 5.3 and later.

Comment: tx. I think I have misunderstood late static binding. It appears it has something to do with doing child class stuff from the parent class

Comment: Yeah it is quite confusing at first, but basically you are on the right track. Using `static` in the parent classes allows those parent classes to access properties, constants, and methods from the derived classes at runtime, if the call was made by a derived object.  While `self::FOO` refers to `FOO` from class `A` because `bar` is defined in `A`, `static::FOO` can refer to `FOO` from class `B` because we ultimately invoked `bar()` from `B`, even though `bar()` is defined in `A`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example there isn't enough going on to see a difference. However, if you had:

```
class Foo
{
  protected static $FooBar = 'Foo';

  public function FooBar()
  {
    echo "static::\$FooBar = " . static::$FooBar . PHP_EOL;
    echo "self::\$FooBar = " . self::$FooBar . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
  protected static $FooBar = 'Bar';
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->FooBar();
```

You'd see the difference (with scope and which instance is being resolved [inherited vs. base])

[**self**, **parent** and **static** keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference. In your sample code, both `self` and `static` refer to the same `const FOO` declaration.

The example sent by user "drew010" shows the difference.